# LSZ fermions (Srednicki's book)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, correlation-functions, s-matrix-theory

In Srednicki's book it is stated that the LSZ formula for fermions holds only if the interacting field $\psi(x)$ is normalized to satisfy $$\langle p,s|\psi(x)|0\rangle = v(p,s)\ e^{ipx}$$ a condition that is stated to follow from Lorentz invariance (up to a scale factor--the wavefunction renormalization constant).
$|p,s\rangle$ is a 1-particle state.  Why is the above condition a consequence of Lorentz invariance, for an ***interacting*** field?